# MyBatis - Holding multiple types

Tags: types, insert, mybatis

Before starting, here is the structure of my classes

- Personne

  - PersonnePhysique (extend Personne)
  - PersonneMorale    (extend Personne)

    - Entreprise  (extend PersonneMorale)
    - Association (extend PersonneMorale)

I'm trying to insert a "Personne" in database, and i need to check if it is a "PersonnePhysique", "Entreprise" or "Association".
So, i did this in my mapper :

```
<insert id="creerPersonne" parameterType="Personne">
   ....

<choose>
    <when test="getClass() instanceof fr.maaf.personne.PersonnePhysique">
        1, 
    </when>
    <when test="getClass() instanceof fr.maaf.personne.Association">
        2, 
    </when>
    <when test="getClass() instanceof fr.maaf.personne.Entreprise">
        2, 
    </when>
</choose>

  ...
</insert>
```

But none of this test pass. 
What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, albeit not in the official doc it shouldn't be a problem for future versions: if test="_parameter instanceof fr.maaf.personne.Entreprise"